# How to add a css class in a loop to the 2nd, 5th, 8th and 11th item

Tags: silverstripe

I have a loop in a SilverStripe template. On the 2nd, 5th, 8th, 11th etc item of the loop I need to add a css class `.service-border`.

How can this be achieved using the SilverStripe template language?

```
<div class="container">
    <% loop $ServiceBlockItems %>
        <% if $First %>
            <div class="row equal-height-columns">
        <% end_if %>

            <%-- Every 2, 5, 8, 11th iteration I need to add a .service-border class --%>
            <div class="col-md-4 service-inner equal-height-column">
                <i class="icon-custom icon-md rounded-x icon-bg-u $IconName"></i>
                <span>$ServiceHeader</span>
                <p>$Summary</p>
            </div>

        <% if $MultipleOf(3) && not $Last %>
        </div><!-- /end row -->
        <div class="row equal-height-columns">
        <% end_if %>
    <% end_loop %>
        </div><!-- /end row -->
</div><!-- /end container -->
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather then adding a class in our template we can use the css `:nth-child` selector to target whichever element we want.

```css
.container .service-inner:nth-child(2),
.container .service-inner:nth-child(5),
.container .service-inner:nth-child(8),
.container .service-inner:nth-child(11) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Or if we want to target every third element starting from element 2 we can use the following css selector:

```css
.container .service-inner:nth-child(3n - 1) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

[`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) is a css3 selector, which now has very good [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

Comment: Perfect, the second example is what I should be doing, have tested and works perfectly. As I want it to be dynamic and not set, so starting from element 2 and styling every third element from then on. Thanks @3dgoo! :)

Answer (score 5):

While I also prefer to use CSS, here's how you would do it using SilverStripe templates:

```
<% loop $Items %>
    <% if $MultipleOf(3, 2) %>
        <div class="item service-border">
    <% else %>
        <div class="item">
    <% end_if %>
        $Value
    </div>
<% end_loop %>
```

Notice the second argument to `$MultipleOf`. You can use it to set an offset.

Comment: Perfect, good to know how to do it in the Silverstripe templates. Thanks! :)

Comment: This is personal preference perhaps, but I would be more inclined to do:

 <div class="item<% if $MultipleOf(3, 2) %> service-border<% end_if %>">